# How to use constants definded in other class file as the default value in a custom annotation

Tags: java, java-8

I hava below custom annotation,

```
@Inherited
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnno {

    String value() default "";

    // use constants value defined in other file
    int capacity() default com.constant.Constant.MAX_DATA_ROW;
}
```

I got a compile error say:

```
"Attribute value must be constant"
```

I don't want to write a direct value to default but I want to refer it from other class.
so how can I accomplish that ?

Comment: It works when `MAX_DATA_ROW` is `static final`

Comment: seems it doesn't recognize your value as a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define `MAX_DATA_ROW` as `static` and `final`:

```
public class Constant {

    public static final int MAX_DATA_ROW = 1;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constant MAX_DATA_ROW must be "public static final", otherwise it isn't a real constant.